# puppeteer unable to load chrome extension in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

This is my first time using puppeteer and I want to open a google chrome page and navigate to a chrome extension I have installed . I try to enable the chrome extension but when I run my script in `headless:false` mode the browser pops up without my extension .

My code :

```
//my extension path 
const StayFocusd = 'C:\\Users\\vasilis\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji\\1.6.0_0';

async function run(){
  
  //this is where I try to enable my extension 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: [`--disable-extensions-except=${StayFocusd}`,"--enable-automation"],
  } 

  );
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();       
  sleep(3000);

  await browser.close();  
}


run();
```

So the extension does not load and I get no error or anything . I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not enough to set `--disable-extensions-except` launch flag with your CRX path, you should also use `--load-extension` to actually load your extension in the opened browser instance.

You also seem to make a mistake using `ignoreDefaultArgs` where you should have used `args` (like this Chromium literally did the opposite of what you've expected).

Correct usage of `puppeteer.launch`:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: [
    `--disable-extensions-except=${StayFocusd}`, 
    `--load-extension=${StayFocusd}`,
    '--enable-automation'
  ]
})
```

You can make use of the official docs about [Working with Chrome Extensions](https://pptr.dev/guides/chrome-extensions) *(link updated on: 2023-03-11).*

Comment: I tested out with headless: "new" and it looks like above code will not work for it

Comment: @rockstone actually the above solution works only with headful mode, extensions don't run in headless mode. ["new" is similar to headless: "true" in this context.](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browserlaunchargumentoptions.headless)

Comment: Actually we can use extensions with headless :"new" check this https://pptr.dev/guides/chrome-extensions but I am testing out on pixelscan it looks like location/timezone is still getting spoofed. No idea how to overcome it

Comment: it can be, I haven't dived deeper into the new headless mode yet. their example should work with the latest version of pptr, in case it doesn't: it is worth raising a GitHub ticket for the maintainers.