# Chrome: 'manifest file is missing or unreadable' when launched by Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I keep getting the same error no matter what, when Puppeteer launches Chrome:

[image]

My code:

```
//....
let pathToExtension = require('path').join(__dirname, 'ext'); // doesn't help
// pathToExtension = none of these work either: the app directory, the chrome extension directory, the chrome user data directory ...
pathToExtension = `E:/ext`
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, //true,
    executablePath: executablePath, 
    args: [`--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}'`,
        `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
       // ignoredDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'], 
       // I would expect the above to allow all extensions, but seems to do nothing
      })
//....
```

I have followed existing solutions here on SO:

- Extension must be unpacked:
  [Failed to load extension and manifest file is missing or unreadable while trying to test Chrome extensions with Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684602/failed-to-load-extension-and-manifest-file-is-missing-or-unreadable-while-trying)
- Both `--disable-extensions-except` and `--load-extension` need to be
  set:
  [puppeteer unable to load chrome extension in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049065/puppeteer-unable-to-load-chrome-extension-in-browser)

Also, my code above is basically one from official docs  https://pptr.dev/guides/chrome-extensions/  .

UPDATE:
Switching `headless: false` to `true` made the error (hopefully not just the message) disappear. However, I still need the extensions to load on headful Chrome.
The doc page (above) states that "*Extensions in Chrome/Chromium currently only work in non-headless mode and experimental Chrome headless mode.*", so I'd expect it to work in headful/non-headless. Not sure abut the "experimental Chrome".

Comment: I feel like you've probably already checked this, but is your manifest in the root directory of the file your uploading for the extension?

Comment: The extensions are installed via Chrome store, I haven't touched them, except for copying to different locations, as mentioned in the code. Manifest.json is present in the original form.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const extensions = [
  path.join(process.cwd(), 'plugins', 'cookies'),
  path.join(process.cwd(), 'plugins', 'ublock-origin'),
];
```